# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1170 BLOB/TEXT column 'group_id' used in key specification without a key length

Tags: magento2.2.2

```
Customer Grid indexer process unknown error:


SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1170 BLOB/TEXT column 'group_id' used in key specification without a key length, query was:

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_grid_flat` (
  `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID' ,
  `name` text NULL COMMENT 'Name' ,
  `email` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Email' ,
  `group_id` text NULL COMMENT 'Group_id' ,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Created_at' ,
  `website_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Website_id' ,
  `confirmation` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Confirmation' ,
  `created_in` text NULL COMMENT 'Created_in' ,
  `dob` date NULL COMMENT 'Dob' ,
  `gender` int NULL COMMENT 'Gender' ,
  `taxvat` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Taxvat' ,
  `lock_expires` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Lock_expires' ,
  `shipping_full` text NULL COMMENT 'Shipping_full' ,
  `billing_full` text NULL COMMENT 'Billing_full' ,
  `billing_firstname` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_firstname' ,
  `billing_lastname` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_lastname' ,
  `billing_telephone` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_telephone' ,
  `billing_postcode` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_postcode' ,
  `billing_country_id` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_country_id' ,
  `billing_region` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_region' ,
  `billing_street` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_street' ,
  `billing_city` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_city' ,
  `billing_fax` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_fax' ,
  `billing_vat_id` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_vat_id' ,
  `billing_company` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_company' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_GROUP_ID` (`group_id`),
  INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CREATED_AT` (`created_at`),
  INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
  INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CONFIRMATION` (`confirmation`),
  INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_DOB` (`dob`),
  INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_GENDER` (`gender`),
  INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_BILLING_COUNTRY_ID` (`billing_country_id`),
  FULLTEXT `FTI_8746F705702DD5F6D45B8C7CE7FE9F2F` (`name`, `email`, `created_in`, `taxvat`, `shipping_full`, `billing_full`, `billing_firstname`, `billing_lastname`, `billing_telephone`, `billing_postcode`, `billing_region`, `billing_city`, `billing_fax`, `billing_company`)
) COMMENT='customer_grid_flat' ENGINE=innodb charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
```

we tried:

on phpmyadmin setting customer_eav_attribute

we changed id 10 (group_id) **is_sercheable_in_grid to value 1**

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED:** also, it needs **is_filterable_in_grid** to be changed also to **value 0**

Comment: If it solved your problem, please accept your own answer (... in some hours :))

Comment: Explaination please?

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes on text/blob columns need an explicit key length.  The entire column length cannot be indexed.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with similar issue after deleting 'customer_grid_flat' table with custom attribute.
The solution was next: set 'is_used_in_grid' to 0 in 'customer_eav_attribute' for problem attribute.